# How to display user input string from EditText in TextView?

Tags: android

I am new to android programming. I keep on getting error and can't find any solution for displaying an input String.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText namex = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    namex.getText().toString();

    final EditText passwordx = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
    passwordx.getText().toString();


    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.signin);
    button.setOnClickListener(
        new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Dispname);
                name.setText(namex);
                TextView password = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Disppassword);
                password.setText(passwordx);
            }
        }

    );


}
```

Help much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: what are the errors???

Comment: Error:(32, 25) error: no suitable method found for setText(EditText)
method TextView.setText(int,BufferType) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method TextView.setText(int) is not applicable
(actual argument EditText cannot be converted to int by method invocation conversion)
method TextView.setText(char[],int,int) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method TextView.setText(CharSequence,BufferType) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

Comment: method TextView.setText(CharSequence) is not applicable
(actual argument EditText cannot be converted to CharSequence by method invocation conversion)

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is you are passing an `EditText` datatype parameter instead of `String` so, try this

```
name.setText(namex.getText().toString());
password.setText(passwordx.getText().toString());
```

Comment: Thanks alot for explaining.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code as below you are setting the reference of `EditText` as text to the`TextView`

```
 Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.signin);
    button.setOnClickListener(
        new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Dispname);
                name.setText(namex.getText().toString());
                TextView password = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Disppassword);
                password.setText(passwordx.getText().toString());
            }
        }

    );
```